# Convergence warning when using mixed effect model

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model

I carried out field observations where I counted the number of birds in a plot, I repeated the observation 4 times for different months. The objective of this is to see if land-use influences the number of birds observed.

My formula is `bird.count ~ lu + (1 | plot)`

`bird.count` a count data with a lot of Zero observations and mean of count = 2 with variance = 5.9, `lu` is a factor with six levels and plot is a factor with 36 levels the where I carried out the repeated observations. In total I've got 144 observations.

Based on all of this I carried out a negative binomial mixed-effect regression, but got warnings regarding failure to converge and the Std.Error of the coefficients are very high and all the same.

I then tried averaging the bird.count of each plot and then had a total of 36 observations. I did this so I wouldn't have to use a mixed effect model. I ran a glm assuming a Gaussian distribution but the Std.Error of the coefficients are very high and all the same.

The things I have tried,

```
fit.x10 <- glmer.nb(bird.count ~ 1 + (1 | plot), 
                    data = birds.data)
```

```
Error in negative.binomial(theta = 2543.33244700468) : 
  unused argument (theta = 2543.33244700468)
In addition: Warning message:
In theta.ml(Y, mu, weights = object@resp$weights, limit = limit,  :
  iteration limit reached
```

```
fit.x11 <- glmer.nb(bird.count ~ lu + (1 | plot), 
                    data = birds.data)
```

```
Error in negative.binomial(theta = 1947.61685250933) : 
  unused argument (theta = 1947.61685250933)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00180515 (tol = 0.001, component 1)
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model is nearly unidentifiable: large eigenvalue ratio
 - Rescale variables?
3: In theta.ml(Y, mu, weights = object@resp$weights, limit = limit,  :
  iteration limit reached
```

```
fit.y10 <- glmmTMB(bird.count ~ (1 | plot), data = birds.data, 
                   family = nbinom2, ziformula = ~ 0, se = TRUE, 
                   verbose = FALSE, doFit = TRUE)
```

```
Family: nbinom2  ( log )
Formula:          bird.count ~ (1 | plot)
Data: birds.data

    AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  501.6    510.5   -247.8    495.6      141 

Random effects:

Conditional model:
Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
plot   (Intercept) 1.434    1.198   
Number of obs: 144, groups:  plot, 36

Overdispersion parameter for nbinom2 family (): 14.2 

Conditional model:
           Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)   0.1303     0.2333   0.558    0.577
```

```
fit.y11 <- glmmTMB(bird.count ~ lu + (1 | plot), 
                   data = birds.data, family = nbinom2, 
                   ziformula = ~ 0, se = TRUE, verbose = FALSE, 
                   doFit = TRUE)
```

```
> fit.y11 <- glmmTMB(bird.count~ lu+  (1|plot), data= birds.data, family = nbinom2,  
+                    ziformula = ~0, se = TRUE, verbose = FALSE, doFit = TRUE)
> summary(fit.y11)
 Family: nbinom2  ( log )
Formula:          bird.count ~ lu + (1 | plot)
Data: birds.data

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   454.1    477.9   -219.1    438.1      136 

Random effects:

Conditional model:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 plot   (Intercept) 0.1946   0.4412  
Number of obs: 144, groups:  plot, 36

Overdispersion parameter for nbinom2 family ():   14 

Conditional model:
                    Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)           -20.51    5531.89  -0.004    0.997
lureserve              21.94    5531.89   0.004    0.997
lunational park        21.48    5531.89   0.004    0.997
lunational park.set    20.62    5531.89   0.004    0.997
luplantation.ns        20.11    5531.89   0.004    0.997
luplantation.cv        21.33    5531.89   0.004    0.997
```

```
fit.z11 <- glm(bird.count ~ lu, data = birds.data.avg, 
               family = gaussian())
```

```
> summary(fit.z11)

Call:
glm(formula = bird.count ~ lu, family = gaussian, data = birds.data.avg)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-3.2500  -0.5625   0.0000   0.7917   3.7500  

Coefficients:
                     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)         4.441e-16  5.886e-01   0.000  1.00000    
lureserve           4.750e+00  8.324e-01   5.707 3.17e-06 ***
lunational park     2.792e+00  8.324e-01   3.354  0.00217 ** 
lunational park.set 1.250e+00  8.324e-01   1.502  0.14361    
luplantation.ns     7.500e-01  8.324e-01   0.901  0.37474    
luplantation.cv     2.458e+00  8.324e-01   2.953  0.00606 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 2.078472)

    Null deviance: 149.500  on 35  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  62.354  on 30  degrees of freedom
AIC: 135.94

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2
```

Any advice on how to diagnose the problem or am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT**
Based on the feed back, yes there is a separation issue, I tried using the GLMMadaptive package but it did not help.

mm1 <- mixed_model(fixed = bird.count ~ lu , random = ~ 1 | plot,
                    data = birds.data , family = negative.binomial() )

This is the error I got,

```
Error in mixed_fit(y, X, Z, X_zi, Z_zi, id, offset, offset_zi, family,  : 
  A large coefficient value has been detected during the optimization.
 Please re-scale you covariates and/or try setting the control argument
 'iter_EM = 0'. Alternatively, this may due to a
 divergence of the optimization algorithm, indicating that an overly
 complex model is fitted to the data. For example, this could be
 caused when including random-effects terms (e.g., in the
 zero-inflated part) that you do not need. Otherwise, adjust the
 'max_coef_value' control argument
```

The alternative solution found is to remove the level from 'lu' variable which has zero observations or removing 'plot' the random effect.

Comment: If land use is a factor and you have no other covariates, the standard errors can only be expected to be the same for each level.

Comment: could you please elaborate, cause that doesn't make sense to me

Comment: @FransRodenburg, I think that's only true for linear models with balanced designs.

Comment: not enough time for a proper answer, but: (1) you do indeed have a complete separation issue (all the values in your first group are zero, I think); you can solve this with `GLMMadaptive` or `blme`, see e.g. complete separation examples [here](http://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/ecostats_chap.html). (2) do you have an alternative `negative.binomial()` function defined?  What do you get from `find("negative.binomial")` ?

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to diagnose the problem without seeing the output and also having access to the data. For example, it could be a separation issue of an issue with the numerical integration over the random effects or even something else.

You could also give a try to the [**GLMMadaptive**](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/) package that can fit the zero-inflated negative binomial mixed model. For example, see [here](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/articles/ZeroInflated_and_TwoPart_Models.html). In addition, if you have a separation problem you could invoke a penalized estimation using the `penalized` argument; for an example see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/386553/linear-mixed-model-for-placement-of-nuclear-stress-in-10-word-turns) and [here](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/articles/GLMMadaptive_basics.html#penalized-mixed-effects-poisson-regression).

Comment: thank you for that, i'll try using the GLMMadaptive package